Olympiad Question on finding the range of Greatest Integer Function?
If $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer not greater than x and
$$f(x) = \left[\frac{x}{12.5}\right]\cdot\left[\frac{-12.5}{x}\right],\quad  0<x<90$$
If the range of $f(x)$ consists of $k$ elements then find the value of k.
You Can Find the question here
What would be the output of this function if we put values between 0 and 90.
--> $[x]$ denotes greatest integer function?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you can replace the introduced operator $[x]$ with the $\mathrm{floor}(x)$ or $\mathrm{ceil}(x)$ in the first and second term respectively. Then you can plot it in GeoGebra, for example, and display your results.

Let us start by examining the case where $x>12.5$. This gives us that the second term will be -1. Then, the first term ranges 1 to 7. This means our range for this section of the domain is $\{-1,-2,…,-7\}$
Then, for $x<12.5$ we have that the first term is 0 and hence the whole expression is 0. Hence our entire range are the integers -7 though 0. This gives us $k=8$.

Clearly first term will make whole function zero for $0<x<12.5$

And for all $x>12.5$ $2$nd term will give $-1$ . so we have to just check first term

For $12.5<x<25$ first term will give $1$ and when x belongs to $25<x<37.5$ then first term will give 2

$\frac{90}{12.5}=7.2$.so there will be $7$ values for $x>12.5$ and one value for $x<12.5$ that is $0$

so the range of function contain total $8$ element $-1,-2,-2....-7,0$
